# UTF-8 Character encoding trouble

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to implement this function to handle clean url's for my page: http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

It works fine for any character when I use it like this:

```
echo toAscii('åäö');
```

But as soon as I test it from an input (again with "åäö") form like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $test = $_POST['test'];
}
echo toAscii($test);
```

I get the following error: Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\bsCMS\ysmt\testurl.php on line 12

This is the complete function toAscii:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

My guess is I have to sync the character encoding from the form to the toAscii function but how?

Comment: Try something to the affect of `$con->set_charset("utf8");` that's always worked for me. Assuming DB connection `$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");`

Comment: Try to use `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on top of your php, and in the html use `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That problem has nothing to do with a MySQL connection. It's the `iconv()` function call which fails.

Comment: What character encoding is your browser set to?

Comment: header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); did the trick, stupid me forgot to include init.php since its just a test page. :) Tomás change your comment to an answer and you get credit.

Comment: Also, any non-ascii characters need to be URL encoded to be valid

Comment: done, there i made it as an answer! thanks

Comment: @ComFreek My bad. Thought it might've helped and misinterpreted the question. In any case, the OP could probably use it for future use. UTF-8 is such a touchy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works:

In the HTML, where the form resides, use:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

To set as a default character encoding to UTF8. That will make the browser set UTF8 and send the variables in POST in UTF8.

Then in your PHP, use the:

`header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

To set the HTTP communication to UTF8.